# Algorithm to create a singly linked list

Tags: c, algorithm

I have an algorithm that should create a singly linked list from a textbook. It barely touched on any examples, so I would need some help figuring it out (still new to C.)

Essentially, the algorithm runs as follows:

```
Algorithm: CREATE (HEAD, ITEM)
1. [Create NEW node]
a) Allocate memory for NEW node.
b) IF NEW = NULL then Print: “Memory not Available” and Return
c) Set NEW→DATA = ITEM
d) Set NEW→LINK = NULL
2. [Whether List is empty, head is the content of HEADER]
If HEAD = NULL then Set HEAD = NEW
3. Else
a) Set Temp = HEAD
b) While Temp→LINK ≠ NULL do
Set Temp = Temp→LINK
[End of while]
c) Set Temp→LINK = NEW
[End of IF]
4. Return
```

Here is what I have tried so far, but I could not understand the arrow mappings in the algorithm. Are these existing `C` features?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node {
    int DATA;
    struct node * LINK;
} node_t;


node_t *create(int head, int item){
    node_t* new =  NULL;
    new = (node_t *)malloc(5*sizeof(node_t));
    if(new == NULL){
        prtinf("Memory not available");
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't skip chapters in your course book. It's nonsensical to try to implement a linked list if you don't understand how struct members are accessed.

Comment: @Cheatah it does not go into much detail about structs, so I guess i'll have to look these up online. The books objective is really to provide a bunch of algorithms

Comment: The algorithm notation is entertaining, though! :) One of the best examples for "obfuscation by documentation". The source text of an implementation is less confusing than the text version. :)

Comment: This suffers from [Shlemiel the painter's algorithm](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arrow operator (`->`) in the algorithm is used to access a member of a struct using a pointer to that struct. It is equivalent to using the dot operator (.) to access a member of a struct, but with the added step of dereferencing the pointer to the struct. For example, if `p` is a pointer to a `struct node`, then `p->DATA` is equivalent to `(*p).DATA`.

In your code, you are using the `node_t` typedef to define the `struct node` type. This means that you can use `node_t *` to refer to a pointer to a `struct node`, and you can use `node_t->DATA` to access the `DATA` member of a `struct node` pointed to by `node_t`.

It looks like you are trying to implement the first step of the algorithm, which is to allocate memory for the new node and store the `ITEM` value in the `DATA` member of the node. You are using `malloc` to allocate memory for the new node, but you need to initialize the `DATA` member and the `LINK` member of the node. You can do this by using the arrow operator to access the members of the node:

```
node_t *create(int head, int item){
    node_t* new =  NULL;
    new = (node_t *)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    if(new == NULL){
        printf("Memory not available");
        return -1;
    }

    new->DATA = item;  // Set the DATA member of the new node
    new->LINK = NULL;  // Set the LINK member of the new node to NULL
}
```

You also need to return the new node from the `create` function so that you can use it later in the algorithm.

```
node_t *create(int head, int item){
    node_t* new =  NULL;
    new = (node_t *)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    if(new == NULL){
        printf("Memory not available");
        return -1;
    }

    new->DATA = item;  // Set the DATA member of the new node
    new->LINK = NULL;  // Set the LINK member of the new node to NULL

    return new;  // Return the new node
}
```

You can then use the `create` function to create a new node and store it in a local variable in your main program. This will allow you to continue implementing the rest of the algorithm.

```
int main() {
    int head = 0;  // The head of the linked list
    int item = 5;  // The data to store in the new node

    node_t *new_node = create(head, item);  // Create a new node

    // Continue implementing the rest of the algorithm...

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thorough explanation! Many thanks for sharing, I understood this and it was simple to digest.